# Doctrine ORM on EAV Tables

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, entity-attribute-value

I was planning on creating my application and use an ORM for the models, but the thing is, there's a part of the database which uses Entity-Attribute-Value Tables.

I pretty liked Doctrine ORM but I don't know if it is possible to maybe create classes that would look like any ordinary doctrine entity, when the table actually hooked up to is of EAV style.

Would it be possible to use Doctrine on this, and if so, how?

Comment: Out of the box, I doubt it. You could probably roll your own implementation. Doctrine is pretty extendible

Comment: Because table relationships according to a value (to join the right attribute-value table according to its data type) isn't possible (as I know), this should be pretty tricky to do that using Doctrine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

definitely possible:

Have relationships like this:
Object (one to many) -> AttributeValue -> Many to One -> AttributeType

Comment: what about if you want to fetch a certain attribute that you have the relation in other table?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem - almost certainly the only solution is you'll have to use an interface in the code to fetch the properties of an EAV attribute, unfortunately, adding a layer of complexity.

Answer (score 4):

In view of [EAV](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Entity-Attribute-Value&action=edit&redlink=1) it seems to be obvious how to build a relation between `entity` and `attribute` using doctrine. In the most complicated case we deal with a [Many to Many](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) relation.

So lets say we want to map an attribute `Name` to an entity `User`. Assuming a user has exactly one name and each name belongs to exactly one user this link can be archived using [One to One](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) relation

But how to model the relation between `attribute` and `value`? The problem is that values can be of different types or even need different numbers of fields in order to save their information.

Consider the attributes `name` and `phone_number`. While a name might be represented by a string, an integer could be needed for the phone number. Or it is even necessary to not only the number but also the area code in a separate filed.

Because EAV requires very flexible value representation, it is not possible to store all of them within the same field in a database table (disregard blobs, data serialization an the like). Therefore most EAV implementations using different tables representing different value types.

In order to reach such flexibility, doctrine features [Inheritance Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#). It basically allows you to extend doctrine entities. Doing so you specify a `discriminator` for each sub-type of your entity:

```
/**
  * @Entity
  * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
  * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="value_type", type="string")
  * @DiscriminatorMap({"name" = "Name", "phone" = "PhoneNumber"})
*/
class Value
{
// ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Name extends Value
{
// ...
}

/** @Entity */
class PhoneNumber extends Value
{
// ...
}
```

The `Value` class provides common implementation for all values, i.e. an id. Each subclass (i.e. `Name` and `PhoneNumber`) extend those common values by their specific ones, for example additional fields.

- The `@DiscriminatorColumn` defines a column in the parent relation which stores the type of the value.
- The `@DiscriminatorMap` is used by doctrine to map the type from the `@DiscriminatorColumn` to one of those classes.

The relation between `attribute` and `value` can be specified to the parent class. Calling values from the attribute then will fetch all types of values which can be filtered (and dealt with) during runtime using for example [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php).

Comment: And if you need 1000 different attributes you have to code 1000 classes? And the user of your application cannot add a new attribute?

Comment: Well you'd create a `StingValue` for example so that the user can add a new value of type `string`... Granted, the PhoneNumber example isn't a very good one. But this concept is EAV, not Doctrine.